# Javascript Module bundling

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and i wanted to learn about modules in general. At the same time I want to use the es6 way of writing modules. Can someone comment on how to set up a work flow for it?

Here is what I have come up with so far.

1. Set up gulp.
2. Use gulp with babel.
3. Use browserify to bundle up modules.

I know how to do up to step 2. However I cant find anything about using browserify to bundle up modules. Why is front side javascript so overly complicated?

Comment: Another popular solution these days is to use webpack. https://webpack.github.io/

Comment: Is not complicated Its matter fo how you wanna code modular If you find difficult scaffolding a manual project use yeoman generators http://yeoman.io/

Comment: How new are you? Because this could be a pretty bad place to jump in as an absolute beginner.

Comment: http://browserify.org/#install

Comment: @DBS I have experience with C#. I'm fine with doing small apps with jquery  etc however I just want my code to be more modular.